# Eslint - 'observer' was used before it was defined?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to solve my order issue I am getting an Eslint error where "observer" was used before it was defined. But when I replace the observer above the onInterSection function I get onIntersection was used before it was defined.

```
(() => {
    let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]')];

    const settings = {
        rootMargin: '50px 0px',
        threshold: 0.01
    };

    const onIntersection = (imageEntites) => {
        imageEntites.forEach((image) => {
            if (image.isIntersecting) {
                observer.unobserve(image.target);
                image.target.src = image.target.dataset.src;
                image.target.onload = () =>
                    image.target.classList.add('loaded');
            }
        });
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, settings);

    images.forEach((image) => observer.observe(image));
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and write it like this:

```
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((imageEntites) => {
        imageEntites.forEach((image) => {
            if (image.isIntersecting) {
                observer.unobserve(image.target);
                image.target.src = image.target.dataset.src;
                image.target.onload = () =>
                    image.target.classList.add('loaded');
            }
        });
    };, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any chance of changing the loader image?

Comment: I don't know what your loader image is. Btw you can also use `loading="lazy"` on the image directly to implement lazy loading of images.

Comment: Yes, but I need support for Safari too this isn't supported there yet.

Comment: then you need your solution, that's correct.